# Hide non-enhanced html in Jquery-Mobile app

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

with my app (Jquery-mobile + Phonegap Build), sometimes, the unenhanced html single-page markup is displayed, just after the splash page, for a second or two.

Did you encounter this problem ?
Can you help me find a way so that the user doesn't see this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've seen this.

Look in the docs - you can usually increase the time the splash screen is displayed.

Alternatively create your own second splash screen - a screen you show only on first starting the app.

Comment: That's what I did, I put a very long time for the splashscreen, and manually hide the splashscreen on pageshow of the first page.... but still see this non enhanced html on android...